# Замена, вставка, удаление текста в файле

Tags: winapi, файлы, c++

Привет всем. Подскажите пожалуйста. В общем есть текстовый файл. Нужно прикрутить функционал вставки, замены и удаления некоторой части файла. К примеру(формат txt файла): ААА. BBB. CCC. DDD. Т.е. обыкновенный файл, состоящий из предложений разделенными точками. Мне допустим захотелось заменить или вставить вместо предложения BBB. предложение EEE.

**void replace(EEE, position) или void insert(EEE, position).**

Все данные у меня по предложениям есть, т. е. номер и позиция в файле. Т.е. установить поинтер в начало предложения не проблема. Нужно записать только через WriteFile.

Comment: вычитываете файл в память, модифицируете как нужно и записываете в файл. Если нужно вставить где то в середине, то можно вычитать только от этого места до конца, вернуть указатель на нужную позицию, вставить текст, вставить сохраненный кусок.

Если нужно заменить данные и кол-во перезаписываемых байт совпадает, то можно просто перезаписать по верху.

Comment: идея не плохая, но тут такой варик, что файло может быть 1-3Гб.

Comment: сорри, забыл указать в условии.

Comment: ну тогда нужен дополнительный файл.

Comment: @jaroslav, больше ничего не забыли указать в условии?

Например, что замен (известных перед запуском программы) может быть несколько.

Comment: Если не требуется поддержка sparse-файлов, то совсем просто - читать и писать в цикле. Но сбой питания может все сломать, поэтому обычно используются структурированные файлы, в которые изменения сначала записываются, а потом применяются записью одного блока. Если нужно проще - писать в копию файла с нужными изменениями, потом избавиться от оригинала (не всегда возможно с множеством пользователей).

Comment: да, может быть и несколько замен. как тогда поступить? каждый раз создавать файл, записывать то, что неизменно, потом что поменяли, старый файл затирать, новый сохранять, переименовывать и т.д.? а если нужно десять замен или вставок, а файлы "жирные".

Comment: хотя можно подумать над идеей maxleo

Comment: Для нескольких замен надо сначала вычислить план изменений, а затем за один проход реализовать его. 

При известном упорстве можно все сделать и без второго файла (но с достаточно большим, скажем для Ваших гигов, пусть будет 100М, буфером).

Comment: Большой буфер не нужен. Если совсем нужно обойтись одним файлом, то можно подумать в сторону cow/shadowcopy/etc, но новичкам я бы не рекомендовал. В случае нескольких изменений чуть сложнее - нужно знать их заранее и обрабатывать за один проход, это вполне очевидно. Ну и место для выходного файла лучше посчитать сразу, во избежание фрагментации.